# styles not accessible before and after authenticated (ASP.NET forms authentication)

Tags: asp.net, styles

I just built an application with forms authentication.  I am unable to see my styles in the application (before being authenticated on Login.aspx NOR on a page after being logged in successfully).  They used to be accessible when the app was using windows authentication.

I read another forum that said you must give access to the App_Themes folder containing the css prior to authenticating, but read above again (I also can't see them after authenticating).  That was working before when using Windows authentication.  I brought in another menu library, so you'll see 3 sections now.

I'm using Windows 7.  Oh, and I right clicked the root folder containing my website files.  I added permissions to IIS_IUSRS group, and IIS APPPOOL[APP POOL NAME] in IIS 7.  I gave all permissions to both.  Also, I have Basic Authentication enabled, and Forms authentication enabled in my site.  The rest are disabled.

Thanks Stack Overflow Geniouses!!

==========================

## web.config

Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->

<!--<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true"
         protection="All" timeout="60" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>-->

  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="WANTA-AUTHENTICATE"
             loginUrl="Login.aspx"
             protection="All"
             timeout="5"
             path="/">
          <credentials passwordFormat="MD5" />
      </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>      



<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Default.aspx">

</customErrors>

<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>

<!--  SESSION STATE SETTINGS
      By default ASP.NET uses cookies to identify which requests belong to a particular session. 
      If cookies are not available, a session can be tracked by adding a session identifier to the URL. 
      To disable cookies, set sessionState cookieless="true".
-->
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="55" />
```

```
<system.serviceModel>

<!--<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" >
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://localhost/" />
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>-->

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

 <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>       
    <service name="Wanta.Toolkit.WantaService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">            
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Wanta.Toolkit.WantaService" />            
    </service>        
</services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

==================

## Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void Logon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((UserEmail.Text == "x") &&
            (UserPass.Text == "x"))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage
           (UserEmail.Text, Persist.Checked);
    }
    else
    {
        Msg.Text = "Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I always remember giving access to the files of my site by right clicking the root folder of my site, and giving access to the following:

server (aka Location): local machine
IIS_IUSRS <=== this is a group
IIS APPPOOL[web_site_app_pool_name]

However, for some reason, IUSR was not in the group IIS_IUSRS.  I ended up just giving that IUSR user access to my site, and not the group.  I learned that you can actually put the user IUSR into the group IIS_IUSRS by going to Computer > Manage > Manage Users & Groups > ...

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your `web.Config` file under the `Configuration` section. It will allow access of an anonymous user to the `App_Themes` Folder.

```
<location path="App_Themes">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, this wasn't the answer to my issues.  I gave you a point anyway.  This would be the answer if the site couldn't access the styles when not authenticated, but could when authenticated.  The allow users="*" gives everyone access, not matter if they're authenticated.  In my case, the site couldn't access the style files at all.  I'll post what was happening below.

Answer (score 2):

I would try adding a custom location to your web.config and allow * for that and see if it will pick the styles up.

Comment: unauthenticated may be a `?` but +1 as I think this is the right direction